# Add item to array of arrays based on id

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays set up like so. There are a total of 10 arrays but I will just display the first 2. The second column has a unique id of between 1-10 (each only used once).

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => User1
            [1] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => User2
            [1] => 3
        )
)
```

I have another array of arrays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 10.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 47.00
        )
)
```

where the first column is the id and the second column is the value I want to add to the first array.

Each id (1-10) is only used once. How would I go about adding the second column from Array#2 to Array#1 matching the ID#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tons of ways to do this :) This is one of them, optimizing the second array for search and walking the first one:

[Live example](http://ideone.com/EZGRSW)

```
<?
$first_array[0][] = 'User1';
$first_array[0][] = 5;
$first_array[1][] = 'User2';
$first_array[1][] = 3;

$secnd_array[0][] = 3;
$secnd_array[0][] = 10.00;
$secnd_array[1][] = 5;
$secnd_array[1][] = 47.00;

// Make the user_id the key of the array
foreach ($secnd_array as $sca) {
    $searchable_second_array[ $sca[0] ] = $sca[1];
}
// Modify the original array
array_walk($first_array, function(&$a) use ($searchable_second_array) {
    // Here we find the second element of the first array in the modified second array :p
    $a[] = $searchable_second_array[ $a[1] ];
});

// print_r($first_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `0` will always be the key of the array and `1` will always be the value you'd like to add, a simple `foreach` loop is all you need.

Where `$initial` is the first array you provided and `$add` is the second:

```
<?php

$initial = array(array("User1", 5),
    array("User2", 3));

$add = array(
    array(0, 10.00),
    array(1, 47.00));

foreach ($add as $item) {
    if (isset($initial[$item[0]])) {
        $initial[$item[0]][] = $item[1];
    }
}

printf("<pre>%s</pre>", print_r($arr1[$item[0]], true));
```

Comment: Shouldn't be: `printf("<pre>%s</pre>", print_r($initial[$item[0]], true));`? And this only return one element

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I got you right, but I've come up with a solution XD

```
<?php
$array_1 = array(
    0 => array(
      0 => 'ID1',
      1 => 5
    ),
    1 => array(
      0 => 'ID2',
      1 => 3
    )
);

$array_2 = array(
    0 => array(
      0 => 3,
      1 => 10.00
    ),
    1 => array(
      0 => 5,
      1 => 47.00
    )
);


foreach($array_1 as $key_1 => $arr_1){
  foreach($array_2 as $key_2 => $arr_2){
    if($arr_2[0] == $arr_1[1]){
      $array_1[$key_1][2] = $arr_2[1];
    }
  }
}

var_dump($array_1);

?>
```

Demo: https://eval.in/201648

The short version would look like this:

```
<?php
$array_1 = array(array('ID1',5),array('ID2',3));

$array_2 = array(array(3,10.00),array(5,47.00));


foreach($array_1 as $key => $arr_1){
  foreach($array_2 as$arr_2){
    if($arr_2[0] == $arr_1[1]){
      $array_1[$key][2] = $arr_2[1];
    }
  }
}

var_dump($array_1);

?>
```

Demo: https://eval.in/201649

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way just to show you one of the more self-explaining ways to do it :)

```
$users = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => 'User1',
        1 => 123
    ),
    1 => array(
        0 => 'User2',
        1 => 456
    )
);

$items = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => 123,
        1 => 'Stuff 1'
    ),
    1 => array(
        0 => 456,
        1 => 'Stuff 2'
    )
);

foreach($items as $item){
    foreach($users as $key => $user){
        if($item[0] == $user[1])
            array_push($users[$key], $item[1]);
    }
}
```